# How to detect failing unit test using rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I am using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.8. This uses rake 0.9.2.2.

I wish to detect a failing unit test and, in Rails 2.3, we did this by checking the exit code. This no longer works.

I try:

```
rake test:units TEST=test/unit/failing_test.rb RAILS_ENV=test && echo "OK"
```

failing_test.rb consists of a single test which asserts false. I expect to see a test failure and not to see "OK", but instead, I see:

```
Started
F
===============================================================================
Failure: <false> is not true.
test: failing test case should fail. (FailingTest)
test/unit/failing_test.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <class:FailingTest>'
shoulda-context (1.0.0) lib/shoulda/context/context.rb:398:in `call'
shoulda-context (1.0.0) lib/shoulda/context/context.rb:398:in `block in create_test_from_should_hash'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:72:in `block in run'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__3774233495015181374__setup__985181848351195933__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:70:in `run'
===============================================================================


Finished in 0.002753 seconds.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
0% passed

363.24 tests/s, 363.24 assertions/s
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/b...]

Tasks: TOP => test:units
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
OK
```

Specifically, I see "Command failed with status (1)", but this seems to get eaten up by rake as I also see "OK". Note that if I do `echo $?`, I see the exit code is 0 (success). I'm trying to get this to work in the context of our continuous integration and also with our release script, both of which assume the exit code will be non-zero in the case of an error, as happened with Rails 2.3.

Comment: Note that there was a similar bug in Rails itself eight months ago, see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4923  However, this is was fixed and I verified that the committed fix remains in 3.2.8.

Comment: Can't reproduce with ruby 1.9.3-p194, rails 3.2.8, rake 0.9.2.2 (and shoulda-context 1.0.0). Can you post your `gem list` output and maybe the body of your test file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My failing test with the same rails/ruby/rake is exiting `1` unlike yours. Perhaps you have something calling `at_exit { exit 0 }` or `trap('EXIT') { exit 0 }` somewhere in your code base. This would modify the exit code for rake.

If you want a non-Ruby way of detecting failures you could try reading the output of the test using `grep`. `grep` will return 0 if it finds a match and 1 if it did not.

the regular expression looks for `" 0 failures, 0 errors"`, returning `0` if it found and `1` if not.

```
rake test:units TEST=test/unit/failing_test.rb RAILS_ENV=test | \
  tee >(xargs -0 echo {}) | \ 
  grep '\([[:space:]]0[[:space:]]\)failures,\1errors' && 
  echo OK
```

Comment: Thank you, lastcanal (and Araxia, above). This is really interesting, I will have to do a minimal example tomorrow to see what the heck is going on. I'd hate for one of our gems or plugins to be mucking about with this, but that's where the signs are pointing. +100 rep will likely expire before I get a chance, but if accurate, I'll see if I can award the rep after it expires.

Comment: This was indeed the problem, though the at_exit block wasn't explicitly returning anything. I modified your answer to show how to work around the issue.

Comment: was at_exit being called from a gem?  Would be useful to know which gems are messing this up.

Comment: I ran into this issue when I was using the copycopter gem.